# Update only part of a string in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a note sharing app built on react and firebase. All the content of a note is saved a string in firebase.

How do i update only changes in the string rather than sending and receiving all data to firebase every time a letter is typed.

Comment: The question is unclear as no code was included in the question and why are you sending and receiving data every time a letter is typed? Why don't you type the note and then send it to firebase when the user clicks the 'send' button?

Comment: think of google docs. has to update after every letter or the user experience of real time sharing and collaboration will be broken

Comment: If you really want to keep a live copy of your data there are several options 1) As the user types, send that string only to Firebase as the user types each character. It's actually not a lot of bandwidth but can be laggy if not handled correctly. 2) Implement a timer that uploads the string every 5s if it has changed. 3) Firebase persistence may be something that you may want to implement. 4) Create a buffer node that stores individual characters, so you are only ever sending one character at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If the note is stored as a single property you can only change its value. So yes, you have to send the whole note.

Comment: What does *a single property* mean? Firebase has key: value pairs and a value can always be changed so it's unclear what you mean by *only change it's value*. What does *send the whole note* mean? More importantly, the OP appears to be writing to Firebase with each keypress so this answer doesn't appear to be related to the question. Can you include a code snippet to clarify the answer?

Comment: Yes, the requests to the back-end should be denounced and required to be distinct from the model state to minimise the number of requests made to the Firebase Database.

As you have pointed out the choice of words might not be as accurate as it should be, however, I was making a point that you cannot update a part of a string without modifying the value of a note.